# Another way of doing GET

Tags: post, get

I have seen on varias different websites that when a forum post or something like that is doing they all have different URLs that make it look like they are in different directories, but I am sure they cannot make different directories for each post.

If you look at this website: https://oc.tc/forums/topics/5181a374ba6087261f000c59

The number at the end (5181a374ba6087261f000c59) changes for each post and it looks liek this is a different directory but I am sure it is not!

Could you please explain how they do this?
Thanks in advance!
Rob

Comment: They are just rewriting the ending portion of the URL, likely using something like mod_rewrite. Or some routing feature inside of their framework.

Answer (score 0):

Use apache [.htaccess](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html) file to handle redirect to your php script

Answer (score 0):

What they're doing there is providing the 518.... as a query string parameter. Their site interprets the request as http://oc.tc/forums/topics/{post}.  It would be the same as doing something like http://oc.tc/forums/topics?post=5181a374ba6087261f000c59 (this is an example to show the idea).

Answer (score 0):

Those sites use a technique called URL rewiring at Apache.

What they do is that they convert URL requests like this:

```
http://site.com/products/categoryA/myawesomeproduct
```

To something internal like:

```
http://site.com/?query=products/categoryA/myawesomeproduct
```

Then the process the rest in PHP. You can learn how to it with examples on the following link: http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html

---

Edit:

A full guide to redirects here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html